# Android studio gradle error

Tags: android-studio, gradle

I updated `buildToolsVersion` to **22.0.1** and I got this error :

```
AAPT warning(Job{title=Cruncher 

com_facebook_button_like_background.png, latch=BooleanLatch{signaled=false}, result=false}): Unknown command
AAPT warning(Job{title=Cruncher emoji_1f603.png, latch=BooleanLatch{signaled=false}, result=false}): Unknown command
AAPT warning(Job{title=Cruncher emoji_1f601.png, latch=BooleanLatch{signaled=false}, result=false}): Unknown command
AAPT warning(Job{title=Cruncher ic_school_black_36dp.png, latch=BooleanLatch{signaled=false}, result=false}): Unknown command
AAPT warning(Job{title=Cruncher common_full_open_on_phone.png, latch=BooleanLatch{signaled=false}, result=false}): Unknown command
AAPT warning(Job{title=Cruncher emoji_1f602.png, latch=BooleanLatch{signaled=false}, result=false}): Unknown command
AAPT warning(Job{title=Cruncher com_facebook_button_like_icon.png, latch=BooleanLatch{signaled=false}, result=false}): Unknown command
AAPT warning(Job{title=Cruncher orca_attach_camera_pressed.png, latch=BooleanLatch{signaled=false}, result=false}): Unknown command
AAPT warning(Job{title=Cruncher ic_launcher.png, latch=BooleanLatch{signaled=false}, result=false}): Unknown command
AAPT warning(Job{title=Cruncher ic_save_white_24dp.png, latch=BooleanLatch{signaled=false}, result=false}): Unknown command
AAPT warning(Job{title=Cruncher abc_ic_clear_mtrl_alpha.png, latch=BooleanLatch{signaled=false}, result=false}): Unknown command
AAPT warning(Job{title=Cruncher emoji_2b50.png, latch=BooleanLatch{signaled=false}, result=false}): Unknown command
AAPT warning(Job{title=Cruncher emoji_2b1c.png, latch=BooleanLatch{signaled=false}, result=false}): Unknown command
AAPT warning(Job{title=Cruncher abc_ic_search_api_mtrl_alpha.png, latch=BooleanLatch{signaled=false}, result=false}): Unknown command
AAPT warning(Job{title=Cruncher com_facebook_button_blue_focused.9.png, latch=BooleanLatch{signaled=false}, result=false}): Unknown command
AAPT warning(Job{title=Cruncher emoji_2b55.png, latch=BooleanLatch{signaled=false}, result=false}): Unknown command
AAPT warning(Job{title=Cruncher ic_arrow_drop_up_white_24dp.png, latch=BooleanLatch{signaled=false}, result=false}): Unknown command
AAPT warning(Job{title=Cruncher abc_ic_ab_back_mtrl_am_alpha.png, latch=BooleanLatch{signaled=false}, result=false}): Unknown command
AAPT warning(Job{title=Cruncher emoji_2b1b.png, latch=BooleanLatch{signaled=false}, result=false}): Unknown command
AAPT warning(Job{title=Cruncher ic_fa_wrench.png, latch=BooleanLatch{signaled=false}, result=false}): Unknown command
```

And the Gradle: Executing Task never ends!

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1):

I went round the houses on this one, my final step, and the one that seemed to get it working was to change

classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.0'

to

classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.1.2'

in the top level build.gradle.

However in the process I did the following

1. Upgraded Java to build 1.8.0_45-b14
2. Changed to using the individual Google Play Services
3. Changed buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"
4. Deleted .gradle in the projects home directory
5. Cleared the caches and restarted a number of times

Comment: Thanks, this works by changing my classpath to my latest version.